# не видны страницы в подпапках Yii2: The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: yii2, apache2

Стандартная страница Yii2 "http://yii2/" - открывается.
Страницы в подпапках Yii2 типа "http://yii2/frontend/web/index.php" и все остальные - не открываются.
ответ сервера:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at yii2 Port 80
```

Что может быть настроено неверно (или что, в приложении к этому вопросу, я, может быть недопонимаю - только начинаю разбираться в теме)?

***hosts:***

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   pc-name

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1   eg
127.0.0.1   yii
127.0.0.1   yii/frontend/web/
127.0.0.1   yii2
127.0.0.1   yii2/frontend/web/
127.0.0.1   firstsite.loc
```

Comment: может кто сказать почему этот вопрос остается без внимания? не тот профиль ресурса (тогда где его лучше задать?), неинтересный, задевает чьи-либо инженерные чувства, другие причины?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

дело оказалось в настройках apache2.
в файле /etc/apache2/sites-available/yii2.conf  сократил строку     `DocumentRoot /var/www/yii2/frontend/web/` до
`DocumentRoot /var/www/yii2/`
всем спасибо за внимание